# How to upload JSON file in Azure DocumentDB using ARM Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell

I have some json files which i want to upload on Azure DocumentDB. How can do this using ARM powershell.

Even i would like to write DocumentDB queries using ARM Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post which answers this question, [Managing DocumentDB with Powershell](https://russellyoung.net/2016/06/18/managing-documentdb-with-powershell/) and includes a script and a walkthrough of what the script does and how it works.  I wrote this to be consumed by a VSTS Build/Release task, which I'm just writing up and should be publishing in the next few days.  (This lets you choose "Publish document to DocumentDB" in your release management process.)

Comment: Your SSL is outdated, and the site is down. Tag me when its up :)

Comment: Will do. Thanks - been meaning to do that for a week or two!  You should be able to get to the site if you ignore the warning.

Comment: Except plugin error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ApplicationInsights\WordPress\Server_Instrumentation' not found".

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in Azure PowerShell cmdlets for CRUD operations with DocumentDB. You'd need to write your own. Alternatively, you can use the REST API directly, or work with one of the language SDK's.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide some references for the REST API.

Comment: Is there any plan in future to handle DocumentDB using powershell

Comment: DocumentDB REST API: A google search should suffice. Future plans / roadmap can't be discussed here.

Comment: @Amit Here is the MSDN link for documentdb rest apis 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt622086.aspx 
SideNote: Wanted to shared this link of Powershell cmdlets for DocDB GitHub project (This is not officially supported), hope this helps to get you started
https://github.com/savjani/Azure-DocumentDB-Powershell-Cmdlets